# "Validate with" meaning in this context

Tags: sentence-meaning

As dictionary says:

**Validate** means-- check the validity or accuracy of something.

E.g.  The data is validated by the computer.

But in the sentence below:

> I agree to validate my voter id card details **with** my ration card.

Does it mean to compare **voter id card details** to **ration card details**?

Please explain.

Comment: Using X and Y makes your question confusing.  Are X and Y people? Things? Adjectives? Please don't use X and Y in questions, use the actual words.

Comment: @JamesK X is voter id card and Y is ration card

Answer (score 1):

As the dictionary notes, validate means "check the validity or accuracy" of something.

In the example given you use the details on the ration card to check the details on the voter id card. You agree that the voter id card details can be checked by someone comparing the information on the voter id card with the details on your ration card.